# Reading the metadata of a TDMS file in python

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to read just the metadata of my TDMS files but my code reads the whole file. Does someone has experience with this? Thank you.

This is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
from nptdms import TdmsFile as td

with td.open('c:\data\AM\Desktop\X\file1.tdms') as tdms_file:
    print(tdms_file)
    td('c:\data\AM\Desktop\X\file1.tdms').as_dataframe().to_excel('c:\data\AM\Desktop\X\file1.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please share your code so we can help. Thanks

Comment: @MohamedAliJAMAOUI I added my code in the question.

Comment: Can you tell us also what is not working with the current code? Maybe you can share a simple/small tdms file? It is a format I have not heard of before! so it would help us help you :)

Comment: @urban Well my goal is actually to read the tdms file and then directly convert it to Excel so I can analyze it. However, when I do the code above I get the whole bunch of actual data in Excel, this is to big. While I actually just need to metadata (which is the description of the data)

Comment: @ManCity10 I would look into [`tdms_file.read_metadata`](https://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apireference.html#nptdms.TdmsFile.read_metadata) but tbh I have no clue what this returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the documentation, you can read the metadata directly using [nptdms.TdmsFile.read_metadata](https://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apireference.html#nptdms.TdmsFile.read_metadata)

```
import numpy as np
from nptdms import TdmsFile as td

metadata = td.read_metadata(tdms_file_path)
print(metadata.properties)
```

---

Example using a tdms file from the unittests of the nptdms library:

https://github.com/adamreeve/npTDMS/blob/master/nptdms/test/data/Digital_Input.tdms

```
In [2]: from nptdms import TdmsFile as td                                                                                                                                           

In [3]: tdms_file_path = "../../Digital_Input.tdms"                                                                                                                                 

In [4]: metadata = td.read_metadata(tdms_file_path)                                                                                                                                 

In [5]: metadata.properties                                                                                                                                                         
Out[5]: 
OrderedDict([('name', 'Digital_Input'),
             ('format-string', ''),
             ('iteration-based-timing', False),
             ('unit_string', ''),
             ('unit-GUID', '{9F75F685-3F5A-4657-8B49-BA907C49DA69}'),
             ('X-unit-string', 's'),
             ('X-unit-GUID', '{0748B676-82D4-4318-A843-708972E53760}'),
             ('unit-version', 0),
             ('Title', '07/09/2012 06:58:23 PM'),
             ('Prefix', '07/09/2012 06:58:23 PM'),
             ('Author', 'SV-LAB-DESKTOP#1'),
             ('Description', ''),
             ('log-datatype', 'Time-DWDT'),
             ('FileFormatVersion', '2.1'),
             ('WriterVersion', '5.0'),
             ('WriterName', 'LabVIEW SignalExpress 2011'),
             ('DateTime', numpy.datetime64('2012-07-09T23:58:24.000000')),
             ('TimeZone', 'Central Daylight Time'),
             ('timing-mode', 'HWTimed_Continuous'),
             ('DataFormat', 'SingleWaveform'),
             ('IntervalCount', 1),
             ('data-ready-for-viewing', True),
             ('log-duration', 10.0),
             ('log-dt', 0.0005),
             ('log-iteration-length', 1.0),
             ('recording-complete', True),
             ('samples prepared for viewing', 20000)])
```

---

**Extra question**: How to save the metadata into an excel?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(metadata.properties.items(), columns=["property", "value"])
df.to_excel(output_excel_file_path)
```

If you want the property names to be columns in the excel, you can save the results as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([metadata.properties.values()], columns=metadata.properties.keys())
df.to_excel(output_excel_file_path)
```

Comment: Ali  JAMAOUI I have used your code and I added my last line of code to export it to Excel. However, I still get all the data. The excel file is 56.875 KB big :(

Comment: @ManCity10 Please share how you add your "line of code"

Comment: I mean this one @ Mohamed Ali JAMAOUI ``TdmsFile('c:\data\AM\Desktop\X\file1.tdms').as_dataframe().to_excel('c:\data\AM\Desktop\X\file1.xlsx')``

Comment: @ManCity10 If you need only the metadata, don't use as_dataframe, the documentation says clearly that it as_dataframe returns the full data, read here: https://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apireference.html#nptdms.TdmsFile.as_dataframe 

Also, look at the example I added to show how you can extract the metadata

Comment: @ Mohamed Ali JAMAOUI Aha, well that makes sense! Now the next 'problem' is, I need that ``metada.properties`` in an Excel file. How is that done?

Comment: @ManCity10 That's a different question, but I updated by answer to give an example on how to write the results into excel.

Comment: @ Mohamed Ali JAMAOUI Chokran Bro, you really helped me!! Last question if possible. I would like to turn the columns in Excel so that they will be from left to right not top to bottom.

Comment: @ManCity10 I added a second example to save excel as you want.

Comment: Thank you very much men! To bad I cannot send you a message, otherwise I have asked you for other things as well. Do you have a blog or website maybe?

Comment: @ManCity10 You can ask questions on SO and ping me with and I'll try to help whenever possible. Good luck. Salam

Comment: @ Mohamed Ali JAMAOUI I wanted to insert your code in a loop so I could do it for multiple TDMS files. However, I just got 1 excel file in the new folder. I added the code in my question above. Can you tell me why its not working?

Comment: @ManCity10 I am sorry, but you need to create a new question. If we keep add sub-questions to this one then the answer will become too long and useless for other people.

Comment: @ Mohamed Ali JAMAOUI, thats true. I just uploaded a new question. Can you look into it by clicking my profile? Thank you.

Comment: @ManCity10 I answered on the new question.